# Can't update my .NET Maui application net8.0-android

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, maui-android

I'm writing my first .NET MAUI app for the phone. Everything works fine. I'm uploading the installation package to the phone using the command:

`dotnet build -c Release -f net8.0-android /p:AndroidPackageFormats=apk --no-restore`

It installs and everything works.

I'm updating the app, creating a new package with a version one higher, for example 1.1.55:

```
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.1.55</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
<ApplicationVersion>55</ApplicationVersion>
```

I upload the package to the phone and get an error when trying to update the app.

> App not installed as package conflicts with an existing package

I've searched the internet for a solution but unfortunately haven't found one. Of course, uninstalling and reinstalling the app resolves the issue, but doing that every time will be inconvenient for the end user.

Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Is other way to update my application? For this moment im dont want use Google Play Store

Best regards

Comment: I cannot reproduce using the above dotnet command. After generating the apk, I install it on Android device through Android Studio.  It doesn't throw the exception and just cover the previous version on the phone.

Comment: did you use signed apk in the bin\Release\net8.0-android folder?

Comment: Yeah, im use signed apk.
Im solved this by getting signed apk from publish folder